# Page break between section and chapter (report)

Tags: chapters, page-breaking, report

In my document, the section always sticks to the next chapter, although there would be space for it on the first page. If I take away 'New word.' from the third paragraph, both the section and part of the chapter fit on page 1. Can anyone explain the behaviour?

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.6em}

\titleformat{\chapter}{\large\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\newcommand\abstand{-0.3em}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{*0}{\abstand}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{*0}{\abstand}

\makeatletter

% Prevent page break before chapter
\renewcommand\chapter{\thispagestyle{plain}%
\global\@topnum\z@
\@afterindentfalse
\secdef\@chapter\@schapter}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}

\blindtext[1]

\blindtext[1]

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Praesent in sapien. New word. 

\section{Test Section}

Text in in section.

\chapter{Second Chapter}

\blindtext[1]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SX and thanks for the good MWE.

The answer is hidden in plain sight in your code. You have redefined `\chapter` so as to **"prevent page break before chapter"**. And the consequences of that are exactly the kind of situation you're describing.

Using `\usepackage{showframe}` to display the text area's borders:

[image: page 1 without chap 2]

There is enough room at the bottom of page 1 for Sec 1.1, but not enough to *properly* accommodate the beginning of Chapter 2. So the title "Chapter 2" is pushed to page 2.
As it does so, it takes all of Sec 1.1 with it, **precisely because** "a page break before chapter" is prohibited.

I wrote "*properly* accommodate the beginning of Chapter 2". In theory, there is room on page 1 for the title and for one line of text:

[image: chap 2 on page 1]

But this doesn't count as *desirable* in (La)TeX's view. There are penalties in place against typographic [widows, orphans](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-widows) and against orphaned headings. You can change their values, if you wish, but be cautious.

**What to do, then?** I don't know that inhibiting a page break before `\chapter` is really that useful. AFAICS, it only gets you in this kind of situations. Personally, I'd get rid of the code.

Alternatively, in this specific instance, you want to issue a `\clearpage` right before `\chapter`. (But wait until late in the document editing stage, to see if this is still needed.)

What you get in both cases:

[image: page 1 with sect 1 1]

Comment: Thank you very much, marquinho, for the straightforward explanation. To redefine \chapter completely would probably lead into other issues. So I will stop using \chapter and start at \section.